# Load a local JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, requirejs

I'm trying to load a local JSON file to populate a table with it.
I've tried requireJS, but it gave me an error:

> MODULE NAME ... HAS NOT BEEN LOADED YET FOR CONTEXT

So I installed the requireJS plugins with bower, though I'm not sure if they are working correctly.
This is the code:

```
    <script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
    function populate() {
        require(['json!sortedAccounts.json'], function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                var $row = "<tr>"
                var account = json[i][0]
                $row.append("<td>" + account + "</td>")
                var friends = json[i][1]
                $row.append("<td>" + friends + "</td>")
                $row.append("</tr>")
                $('loadedJSON').append($row)

            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

The error I get is:

> GET http://localhost:63343/HTML/json.js 
>   Uncaught Error: Script error for "json", needed by: json!sortedAccounts.json_unnormalized2
>   Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: json!sortedAccounts.json_unnormalized2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery you could simply do this:

```
$.getJSON( "sortedAccounts.json", function(json) {
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var $row = "<tr>"
            var account = json[i][0]
            $row.append("<td>" + account + "</td>")
            var friends = json[i][1]
            $row.append("<td>" + friends + "</td>")
            $row.append("</tr>")
            $('loadedJSON').append($row)  // Incorrect selector
      }
});
```